# How check if a value attribute are included in a array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to check if a value of an attribute is included in an array. 
Like that:

```
  @teste = []
  @vacancies_interns.each do |vacancy_intern|        
    @teste << vacancy_intern.id        
  end
  @hr_curriculum_interns = HrCurriculumIntern.where(@teste.include?(:id) == true)
```

The output of the variable @teste, as an example, is:
[5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15]

I am listing the variable @ hr_curriculum_interns on a table, and even with the condition, is listing all table rows.

Sorry for English :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It as simple as:

```
@hr_curriculum_interns = HrCurriculumIntern.where(id: @teste)
```